# Исключение при пустом слоте

Tags: qt5, сигналы-слоты

Есть окно. У него слот с сигнатурой

```
void ECMain::OnProcessProgressEvent(const QString & ATestName,
                                const int AStarStepNum,
                                const int AStepCount,
                                const int ACurStepNum,
                                const QString & AStepName)
```

Если тело слота пустое или содержит только **return**, то при поступлении сигнала на этот слот приложение падает(скорей всего исключение)
Почему так происходит?

Comment: а можно заменить "скорее всего исключение" текстом ошибки при аварийном завершении? пройтись дебаггером, например?

Comment: в выводе приложения - программа завершена принудительно и больше ни гу-гу. С отладчиком у меня проблемки пока. Как настрою гляну.